# linear differential equation help

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to solve this equation

$$x_1'(t) = 2x_1(t) − x_2(t) − x_3(t)\\x_2'(t) = −x_1(t) + 2x_2(t) − x_3(t)\\x_3'(t) = −x_1(t) − x_2(t) + 2x_3(t)$$

I got $\lambda = 0, 3$, with $3$ having a multiplicity of $2$.

Incase $\lambda = 0$, I got 
\begin{equation}
X_1 = t\left[
\begin{array}{x}
1 \\
1 \\
1 
\end{array}
\right],
\end{equation}

but how could I get $X_2$ and $X_3$ when $\lambda = 3$?
$(A-\lambda I)X = 0$ I get only $-x_1-x_2-x_3=0$

Answer (score 1):

You're right, the equationfor $\lambda = 3$ is
\begin{equation}
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 0.
\end{equation}
But this equation has infinite solutions, so you can propose two linear independent solutions of them. For example, if $x_3 = 0$, the equation becomes
$$x_1 + x_2 = 0$$
and then 
\begin{equation}
X_2 = t\left[
\begin{array}{c}
1 \\
-1 \\
0
\end{array}
\right].
\end{equation}
But you need two solutions, either a vector with $x_1 = 0$ or $x_2 = 0$ are linear independent to $X_2$. So, for $x_2 = 0$ the equation becomes
$$x_1 + x_3 = 0,$$
thus
\begin{equation}
X_3 = t\left[
\begin{array}{c}
1 \\
0 \\
-1
\end{array}
\right],
\end{equation}
finally
\begin{equation}
X_2 = t\left[
\begin{array}{c}
1 \\
-1 \\
0
\end{array}
\right],
\hspace{3em}
X_3 = t\left[
\begin{array}{c}
1 \\
0 \\
-1
\end{array}
\right].
\end{equation}

Summary: you can choise any vectors that solve your equation, but those two vectors have to be linear indepent each.